# How to return only rows where no rows from another table using Lambda Expressions in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two tables; **Notification** and **SeenBy**.

Notification:

```
Notification.Id
Notification.Timestamp
Notification.Message
```

SeenBy

```
SeenBy.Id
SeenBy.NotificationId
SeenBy.ClientId
SeenBy.Timestamp
```

I need to get the rows from table **Notification** not seen before (Count=0) using secondary table **SeenBy**.

What would be the Linq query or Lambda expressions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: a left outer join ? am i understanding correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
var seenNotificationIds = seenByCollection.Select(x => x.NotificationId).Distinct();
var seenNotifications = notifications.Where(x => seenNotificationIds.Contains(x.Id));
var notSeenNotifications = notifications.Except(seenNotifications);
notSeenNotifications.Dump();
```

Comment: How about if you add Distinct `var seenNotificationIds = seenByCollection.Select(x => x.NotificationId).Distinct();`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var allNotificationObjects = ...; // all your notification objects
var seenByObjects = ...; // all seen by objects

var seenNotificationIds = seenByObjects
                         .Select(item => item.NotificationId)
                         .Distinct()
                         .ToHashSet();   

var result = allNotificationObjects
            .Where(item => !seenNotificationsIds.Contains(item.Id))
            .ToList(); // all notifications which are not seen
```